# Systemctl with gunicorn permission denied

Tags: flask, gunicorn, systemd, systemctl

I've been working on systemctl for a while and it's just not working.

I have tested with gunicorn and it works perfectly, but when I'm doing this

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable flaskapp
systemctl start flaskapp
```

However, I've been getting issues like this

```
Dec  2 16:17:15 localhost systemd[1]: Started flaskapp.
Dec  2 16:17:15 localhost systemd[2130]: flaskapp.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/flaskappuser/flaskapp/flaskvenv/bin/gunicorn: Permission denied
Dec  2 16:17:15 localhost systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec  2 16:17:15 localhost systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec  2 16:17:15 localhost systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec  2 16:17:15 localhost systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec  2 16:17:15 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped flaskapp.
Dec  2 16:17:15 localhost systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec  2 16:17:15 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start flaskapp.
Dec  2 16:17:21 localhost systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec  2 16:17:21 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Supervisor process control system for UNIX.
Dec  2 16:17:21 localhost systemd[1]: Started Supervisor process control system for UNIX.
```

I tried with sudo and it doesn't work either. I have searched everything online but no result. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Who owns the repo `/home/flaskappuser/flaskapp/flaskvenv/bin/gunicorn`?
 Show us the `ls- al /home/flaskappuser/flaskapp/flaskvenv/bin/gunicorn` output.

Comment: I got  
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 flaskappuser flaskappuser 4096 Nov 29 16:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 flaskappuser flaskappuser 4096 Nov 29 16:19 ..

Comment: Does flaskapp user exists? If yes `sudo chow flaskapp /home/flaskappuser/flaskapp/flaskvenv/bin/gunicorn`